# How to reference a composite primary key into a single field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, composite-primary-key

I got this composite primary key in Table 1:

```
Table 1: Applicant

CreationDate PK
FamilyId PK
MemberId PK
```

I need to create a foreign key in Table 2 to reference this composite key. But i do not want to create three fields in Table 2 but to concatenate them in a single field.

```
Table 2: Sales

SalesId int, 
ApplicantId  -- This should be "CreationDate-FamilyId-MemberId"
```

What are the possible ways to achieve this ?

Note: I know i can create another field in Table 1 with the three columns concatenation but then i will have redundant info

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do that exactly as you want. Just add an Id column to your `Applicant` table and make that the primary key, then add a non-clustered unique index on the other three.

Comment: Whilst one could somehow force it - you would then have to compare a (part of a) string against a date, (probably) some number(s), or a combination thereof. So you should really either follow Alireza, or keep the individual columns intact.

Comment: Attempting to do this as stated is actually a violation of normalization practices, because you end up with multi-part keys.  There's all sort of problems with this, don't do it.  Do what @Alireza says, and create a surrogate id (probably another auto-generated field).

Comment: Having `creationdate` as part of the PK seems suspect anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith The purpose of the creation date is to be able to reset the numbering of the Applicants each day.

Comment: *"But i do not want to create three fields in Table 2..."* Why not?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', because this is not the only table i got that needs to reference this Id, this will add extra code in my application each time i need to reference the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is tantamount to saying "I want to treat three pieces of information as one piece of information without explicitly making it one piece of information". Which is to say that it's not possible.

That said, there are ways to make happen what you want to happen

- Create a surrogate key (i.e. identity column) and use that as the FK reference
- Create a computed column that is the concatenation of the three columns and use that as the FK reference

All else being equal (ease of implementation, politics, etc), I'd prefer the first. What you have is really a natural key and doesn't make a good PK if it's going to be referenced externally. Which isn't to say that you can't enforce uniqueness with a unique key; you can and should.